# WebClient 'Force-closing a channel whose registration task was not accepted by an event loop'

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webclient

I have developed a WebClient that is integrated with Auto2 client_credentials.

```
@Autowired
private WebClient webClient;
List <Device> deviceList = new ArrayList<Device>();


public void getDeviceData(String macAddress) {
    logger.info("** start getDeviceData . **");

    String formatMac = macAddress.replaceAll("(.{2})", "$1"+":").substring(0,17);
    String request = "{ \"cmMac\": \""+formatMac+"\" }";
     
     webClient.post()
        .uri("https:......")
        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).header(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        .body(Mono.just(request), String.class)
        .attributes(ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.clientRegistrationId("...."))
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(String.class)
        .doOnError(e -> logger.error(e.getMessage()))
        .doOnNext(s ->  {
            JsonObject convertedObject = new Gson().fromJson(s, JsonObject.class);
            Device device = new Device();
            device.setMacAddress(macAddress);
            deviceList.add(device);
        }).block();
}


@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    getDeviceData("xxxxxxxx");
    
    for (Iterator iterator = deviceList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        Device device = (Device) iterator.next();
        logger.info(device.getMacAddress());
    }
}
```

Since I am still in the development phase I am using STS to run the program. In general, the function is working well meaning, it will retrieve the access token and then will do the post call to the online service.

When I need to change the code and save the file then the program will fail with the following error:

```
  : Force-closing a channel whose registration task was not accepted by an event loop: [id: 0xba25b296]

 java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: event executor terminated
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.reject(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:926) ~[netty-common-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.offerTask(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:353) ~[netty-common-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.addTask(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:346) ~[netty-common-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.execute(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:828) ~[netty-common-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.execute(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:818) ~[netty-common-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.register(AbstractChannel.java:471) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
at io.netty.channel.SingleThreadEventLoop.register(SingleThreadEventLoop.java:87) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
at io.netty.channel.SingleThreadEventLoop.register(SingleThreadEventLoop.java:81) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.initAndRegister(AbstractBootstrap.java:323) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.register(AbstractBootstrap.java:227) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolver.<init>(DnsNameResolver.java:487) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolverBuilder.build(DnsNameResolverBuilder.java:488) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsAddressResolverGroup.newNameResolver(DnsAddressResolverGroup.java:114) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsAddressResolverGroup.newResolver(DnsAddressResolverGroup.java:92) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsAddressResolverGroup.newResolver(DnsAddressResolverGroup.java:77) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
at io.netty.resolver.AddressResolverGroup.getResolver(AddressResolverGroup.java:70) ~[netty-resolver-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
at reactor.netty.transport.TransportConnector.doResolveAndConnect(TransportConnector.java:208) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.5.jar:1.0.5]
at reactor.netty.transport.TransportConnector.lambda$connect$2(TransportConnector.java:103) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.5.jar:1.0.5]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:125) ~[reactor-core-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
at reactor.netty.transport.TransportConnector$MonoChannelPromise._subscribe(TransportConnector.java:526) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.5.jar:1.0.5]
at reactor.netty.transport.TransportConnector$MonoChannelPromise.lambda$subscribe$0(TransportConnector.java:446) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.5.jar:1.0.5]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164) ~[netty-common-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472) ~[netty-common-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:500) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
```

I am new to WebClient and have no idea what is the root cause of this error.

Any idea what is the issue with this scenario ?

Thanks